How to view locally stored .EML files as if they were in an inbox folder?
This may be a strange question. I use webmail because of its convenience, and to avoid my storage to become full I export emails into .EML files before deleting them from the webmail.
So I have a directory full of .EML files. Sometimes I need to find an old email from this directory so this is my question:
Is there a way to simply visualise this directory as if it was an inbox folder of an email client or webmail?
What I mean is, the content of the directory (hundreds of .EML files) would be shown just like in an inbox, with the title of the email, date/time, sender's name, email, etc, so I can quickly navigate all the .EML files visually and find what I need.
A bot asked me to edit the question to make it specific but don't know how to make it more specific than this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your first task would seem to be to identify email clients that can handle the storage format you're hoping to use, and try them out to see which one you like.  Then the task becomes more well-defined, and you can directly address how to manipulate your message store into a format that your newly-chosen mail reader can work with.

I was looking for a way to visualise the emails in a convenient way, not a way to store them which I already have. I may try something else by renaming files.

hm, why not simply access your mail via IMAP using literally any possible mail client, and on there, make that local copy? Automatically gives you a local email archive that your client of choice can deal with. Alternatively, you can at manageable effort just run your own IMAP server that you move the mails from your webmail to. (Which makes one wonder… emails really don't take up much space, in the greater scheme of things. It feels like if you can still handle the amount of emails by hand using individual files, then it's probably not a technical burden for a mail server. Maybe consider changing your email provider if you're so space-constrained that you can't keep all your emails around – that sounds like a problem that hasn't existed since ca. 2006. My private IMAP server has some 15 GB of emails that it has a full-text index of, and is really quick to react and search. My mail client struggles with the amount of email, but the low-cost VM that my IMAP server runs on is fine. Makes me question whether you really have enough email to worry about, or just need to have a less underwhelming webmail provider. Even the free google, apple mail and so forth offerings have enough space for a power user!)
Anyways, Thunderbird can read MBOX files – it's its native mail archive format. That's just a concatenation of emails (.eml files as you'd call them). cat *.eml > archive.mbox, ideally you create a local folder with a single email in there in thunderbird with a distinctive name, close thunderbirdm, find the local folder storage in your profile (typically, ~/.thunderbird/randomstuff.default/Mail/Local Folders/something), and just overwrite the something with your cat *.eml output, delete the .msf file (if any) next to it and start thunderbird.

Wow thanks, this was helpful. it's making me rethink things a bit. The reason I use webmail (Protonmail) is because I can access my emails from my computer and phones without complications. I considered doing what you suggest but it seemed to complicate things rather than helping.
The archive thing is great. I could make a script to automate it every time I want to update it. Thanks for the help!

but protonmail allows IMAP access while keeping the mails on the server – and that allows any phone (I especially like the K9 mail client) to access them directly, and any desktop :)
